# Does Not Follow Player on update

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Does anyone know Why The layer does not follow the player?

```
void HelloWorld::update (float delta) {
    cocos2d::Size winSize = cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
    this->_player->setPosition(this->_player->getPosition().x , this->_player->getPosition().y + (10 * delta));
    this->_background->setPosition(this->_player->getPosition().x , this->_player->getPosition().y);
    this->setPosition(this->_player->getPosition().x + (winSize.width / 2),
                      this->_player->getPosition().y + (winSize.height / 3)); // Follow The player 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The layer will not follow the player with the code you are using. Cocos2d-x provides you with a [Follow action](http://www.mets-blog.com/cocos2d-x-ccfollow-camera-tutorial/) that you can attach to a node, and run on the layer you want to make follow the player. See below for example code.

```
auto followAction = Follow::create(playerNode, Rect());
// The Rect you give is the bounds the player can move before 
// the camera (layer) starts following it. Giving empty rect will make sure the camera
// follows as soon as your player starts moving.

layerToFollow->runAction(followAction);
```

The code above will cause the layerToFollow to move whenever your player moves around. I hope this helps.